# Create a Pie Chart by category, not Date, in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have 4 columns, the first is Date, and the other 3 are costs (COGS, Fees, Shipping fees).
I want to create a pie chart to see the breakdown between the 3 costs (e.g. a pie chart with 3 slices of 45%, 28% & 27%).
In Google sheets I create the chart and I need to tick the "Switch rows / columns" option and it works fine.
How can I do the same in Google Data Studio? I tried adding all 3 as dimensions, all 3 as metrics and it doesn't change a thing. I still get the breakdown by day (Date) and not the 3 categories.

For example, a table like this:

| Date | COGS | Fees | Shipping |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Jan | 243 | 134 | 125 |
| 2 Jan | 546 | 234 | 324 |

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to tell you that the Data Studio pie chart needs one dimension to split the date into the pie segments. There are several options:

- You unflatten / unpivot your table:
  This task can be done in Big Query.
- You use a "100% stack bar chart":

  - create an empty string field and put it on to the dimension of the x-axis
  - no breakdown dimension
  - add to the metric the field cogs and shipping and fees